# How can I Set Authorization Url in Razor Pages

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

My ConfigureServices as follows:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(o =>
        {
            o.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
    });
```

When an authoriztion required Page is called, it is redirect to login page with a URL like localhost:58731/User/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

How can I set this url like this: localhost:58731/Login/%2F

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend messing with the middle to modify that path. Even though it seems possible from links such as this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x

However you can make a redirect from your `User/Login` location to your desired location. If you are using `User/Login` for something else, you can change `o.LoginPath` to a different location and again use an action something like this:

```
public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl) => Redirect("~/Login/" + ReturnUrl);
```